# Программа не проходит один тест. Помогите увидеть ошибку

Tags: c++

В нереально крутой real-time стратегии «Supreme Commander: Forged Alliance» есть два типа ресурсов: электричество и материя. Материю могут добывать только mass extractor'ы, которые, в свою очередь, можно проапгрейдить максимум до 3 уровня. Наш друг Вася хочет как можно скорее накопить K единиц материи, чтобы наконец достроить парагон. Известно, что mass extractor первого уровня добывает 3 единицы материи в секунду, второго уровня – 9, третьего – 27. Апгрейд с первого до второго уровня длится l2 секунд, со второго до третьего – l3 секунд. Во время апгрейда mass extractor не добывает материю. Изначально у Васи 0 материи и всего 1 mass extractor первого уровня.

Помогите вычислить Васе, за какое наименьшее время он сможет накопить необходимое количество материи.

Входные данные
В единственной строке входных данных содержится 3 числа: K, l2, l3 (1  ≤  K  ≤  109; 1  ≤  l2,  l3  ≤  1000) – количество материи, которое хочет накопить Вася, время апгрейда до 2 уровня и время апгрейда до 3 уровня соответственно.

Выходные данные
Выведите единственное вещественное число с абсолютной или относительной погрешностью не более 10 - 6 – минимально возможное время в секундах, за которое Вася может накопить массу.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    long double  k;
    double l2, l3;
    cin >> k >> l2 >> l3;

    double rez;
    double t1 = k / 3;
    double t2 = k / 9 + l2;
    double  t3 = k / 27 + l2 + l3;

    if (t1 < t2 && t1 < t3) {
        rez = t1;
    }
    else if (t2 < t3) {
        rez = t2;
    }
    else  {
        rez = t3;
    }


    cout << rez;


}
```

Comment: Не может ли быть так, что вам просто нужно точнее выводить ответ? Скажем, дать `cout << setprecision(10)`?

Comment: вполне возможно

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартный вывод `cout` - 6 знаков. Для того, чтобы получить на выходе требуемую точность, следует указать, что вывод должен быть с повышенной точностью, например,

```
cout << setprecision(10) << rez << endl;
```